# Removing specific columns and rows from nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

If for example I have `glider = [[0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4],[0,1,3,4],[0,0,0,0]]`, how would I go about deleting the first and last list as well as the first and last character per list if the nested lists varies. It would look like this after.

```
glider = [[2,3],[1,3]]
```

For example, I can't just simply use the `del` function because the dimensions will vary. ex:`[[0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,0,0,0,0]]`
, `[[0,0,0],[1,2,3],[0,0,0]]`

This is a small part of a bigger program but it has me stumped. Maybe the better method would be to to create a whole new list? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using slicing and a temporary list:

```
glider = [[0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4],[0,1,3,4],[0,0,0,0]]

glider = glider[1:-1]

templist = []

for i in glider:
    templist.append(i[1:-1])
glider = templist
del templist
```

Output:

```
>>> glider
[[2, 3], [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new list with your given conditions

```
glider = [[y for y in x[1:-1]] for x in glider[1:-1]]
```

Comment: This doesn't remove consecutive equal items.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
glider = [[0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4],[0,1,3,4],[0,0,0,0]]

def my_strip(lst):
    if isinstance(lst, list):
        lst = lst[1:-1]
        for idx, val in enumerate(lst):
            lst[idx] = my_strip(val)
    return lst

print my_strip(glider)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like:

```
a = [[0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,0,0,0,0]]
b = [k[1:-1] for k in a[1:-1]]
# remove consecutive equal items
if b:
    res = [b[0]] + [k for i, k in enumerate(b[1:], 1) if k != b[i-1]]
else:
    res = []
```